# How to check to exist a unit systemd on the servers by Prometheus?

Tags: monitoring, systemd, prometheus

I have a service 'service_1' on the servers. And I need checking by Prometheus existing this service on the servers. **node_systemd_unit_state** showing only metrics for existing services. 
Maybe I can check existing file in /etc/systemd/system/service_1.service, but don't understand how to do that by Prometheus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution for this is just monitoring if someone listening to some port on the server, that used by service_1.